# Is it possible to make a state array from this JSON object?

Tags: reactjs, axios, jsx

A newbie in React here. I'm using axios to retrieve this object requested to my Django server rest framework Api:

```
{
    "count": 3,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "url": "http://localhost:8000/blog/api/categories/1/",
            "title": "Django",
            "slug": "django"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "url": "http://localhost:8000/blog/api/categories/2/",
            "title": "Git",
            "slug": "git"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "url": "http://localhost:8000/blog/api/categories/3/",
            "title": "Introduction to docker",
            "slug": "introduction-to-docker"
        }
    ]
}
```

So far I've been able to store those variables in separate arrays. This is the implementation of my FetchDemo.js:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

{/* https://daveceddia.com/ajax-requests-in-react/ */}

class FetchDemo extends Component {
state = {
    urls: []
}
state = {
    titles: []
}
state = {
    slugs: []
}

componentDidMount() {
        axios.get(`${this.props.url}${this.props.path}`).then(res => {
        const urls = res.data.results.map(num => num.url);
        const titles = res.data.results.map(num => num.title);
        const slugs = res.data.results.map(num => num.slug);
        this.setState( {urls} );
        this.setState( {titles} );
        this.setState( {slugs} );
    });
}

render() {
    return (
    <div>
        <h1>{`${this.props.url}${this.props.path}`}</h1>        
        <ul>
            /// How to generate the JSX objects? ///
        </ul>
    </div>
    );
}
}

export default FetchDemo;
```

Is it possible to build in the axios request a state array from this JSON object like the next one instead? How do I generate JSX with this new state categories?

```
this.setState({
        categories: [
        {url: "http://localhost:8000/blog/api/categories/1/", title: "Django", slug: "django"},
        {url: "http://localhost:8000/blog/api/categories/2/", title: "Git", slug: "git"},
        {url: "http://localhost:8000/blog/api/categories/3/", title: "Introduction to Docker", slug: "introduction-to-docker"},
        ]
    }
    )
```

I wish I knew more React and JavaScript. Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use `array#map` to generate the JSX object.

Comment: Of course, I have to use array.map in a similar way to what I already did, but given that I'm starting with JavaScript and React I don't know how exactly to make it. That's the reason I'm asking here in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things to note here.

1. `state` is a single object with multiple keys.
2. `setState()` is a single async transaction. When you are updating your state, you should update it in one go.

You can do things in a simpler way if I understand your question right. You don't have to store the values in multiple keys. It can be stored in a single key `categories`.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class FetchDemo extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      categories = []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`${this.props.url}${this.props.path}`).then((res) => {
      const urls = res.data.results.map((num) => num.url);
      const titles = res.data.results.map((num) => num.title);
      const slugs = res.data.results.map((num) => num.slug);
      this.setState({
        categories: res.data.results
      });
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { categories } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{`${this.props.url}${this.props.path}`}</h1>
        <ul>
          {categories.length ? 
            categories.map(cat => (
              <li key={cat.id}>
                <div>{cat.title}</div>
              </li>
            ))
            : 
            (<li>categories not loaded yet</li>)}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default FetchDemo;
```